# Associate docusign envelope to salesfoce

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm initiating an envelope using the REST API. I was able to set a custom field on the envelope to the salesforce account Id and then once complete upload the final document and update fields.

My next problem is I have some custom tags. In the custom tag settings I've related them to salesforce fields and enabled write back. I can't seem to get these to update salesforce if the information in the document changes. Is there an internal field or value that I need to set for the envelope to associate it with sales force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you've already installed DocuSign for Salesforce in your Salesforce org and have configured it to point to your DocuSign account?  If so, you likely just need to update the "(Salesforce) Connect" configuration in DocuSign to explicitly tell it to write back the fields. I don't believe "merge fields" will write back data to Salesforce for envelopes that are initiated via the API.

This guide contains info about updating Connect settings for the DocuSign for Salesforce Connect configuration:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20Connect%20for%20Salesforce.pdf. Specifically, content relevant to your scenario starts on page 4 under heading "**DocuSign Connect for Salesforce Settings** -- and especially within item **#7. To edit, add, delete, or change the order of Connect Objects** that begins on page 6.

Within the "Salesforce" Connect Configuration in DocuSign, you can add a new "Connect Object" to have DocuSign automatically update a specific type of object in Salesforce based upon criteria you specify.  For example, let's assume that you want to automatically update a **Contact** record in Salesforce (using data from DocuSign fields in a completed envelope) whenever a completed envelope contains a DocuSign secure field called **HCP_ID**, and the value in the **HCP_ID** DocuSign field matches the **HCP_ID** field value on a Contact record in Salesforce.  Creating a Connect Object like the following would accomplish this:

[image: SF Connect Custom Object]

The field mappings in the "**Update Fields**" section specify which values in Salesforce you want to update with which DocuSign values.  (See the guide I've linked to above for more information -- it explains things in much greater detail than I've done here.)